# Which manuals are on your "TeX Reference" shelf?

Tags: books, documentation

This is a community wiki since there is no "one true answer"- if you find an answer that contains a lot of your choices, but is missing something you feel is incredibly useful.  Feel free to add it.  A short description of what topics the reference covers would be nice as well.

Organize by subject please.

For example: I always keep the following PDFs at my fingertips.

#### Document Layout

- [The Memoir manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/):  Covers, in exquisite detail, how to produce just about any document using the `memoir` LaTeX class. ([PDF](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) 4.5 MB)

#### Mathematical Typesetting

- [Math Mode](http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/): A document by Herbert Voß that explains how to typeset just about any mathematical expression in LaTeX. ([PDF](http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) 2 MB)

#### Graphics

- [The PGF Manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf): Explains, with examples, how to draw just about any figure using PGF/TikZ.  Also a good example of what awesome documentation should look like. ([PDF](http://mirror.macomnet.net/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) 9.5 MB)

Comment: Those examples you put in the question would make good answers, I think...

Comment: The memoir and PGF manuals are superb!

Comment: Interesting idea of a shelf you have there. (Admittedly, I believe that most of the hard-copy TeX-related reference books I use are currently in a clothes basket in my bedroom...)

Comment: I do wish The PGF Manual would be printed in a book format...

Answer (score 37):

For now, I will post reference manuals that haven't been mentioned here yet.

#### LaTeX

- For LaTeX itself there's a great reference: [source2e.pdf](http://ctan.org/pkg/source2e). It's usually part of a LateX distribution, so I quickly access it by `texdoc source2e` and enter a keyword to the search feature of the pdf browser.

#### Presentations

- The [beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) manual is so comprehensive that it serves me often as reference. Again, I use `texdoc beamer`.

#### Document Layout

- I appreciate the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) manual by Markus Kohm. In German it's still more extensive, but I hope the English version will be improved as well. The manual addresses many aspects of layout and typographic style. `texdoc scrguien` or `texdoc scrguide`.

#### Mathematical Typesetting

- Besides Herbert Voss' great Mathmode.pdf, the [amsmath user's guide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) is a valuable reference because amsmath is the standard package for mathematica typesetting. `texdoc amsldoc`

#### Symbols

- The common reference is the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) by Scott Pakin containing about 6000 symbols and how to typeset them. `texdoc symbols-a4`

#### Hypertext and PDF features

- The probably most important reference is the [hyperref manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html). It deals with nearly all you need to know about hyperlinks and PDF bookmarks. What it doesn't tell yet, may be read in the [README file](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf) to that package. `texdoc hyperref/manual` and `texdoc hyperref/readme`
- Further there's the [pdfTeX user manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/pdftex/pdftex-a.pdf). `texdoc pdftex-a`

#### TeX

- Besides the great TeX-by-Topic reference, the [TeXbook](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/texbook.html) by Donald E. Knuth is my reference because I like to read the documentation written by the TeX creator itself even if it's not so accessible like the first mentioned book.

#### Bibliographies

- [BibTeXing](http://mirror.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxdoc.pdf) by Oren patashnik is a good reference for BibTeX. For instance, it lists entry and field types. `texdc btxdoc`

`texdoc` is the tool for quick access, but one should know for what to look out. Earlier it was difficult because one had to remember complicated file names, but today `texdoc` understands commonly used aliases.

Comment: Hmm, I mostly prefer `pdftex-s` over `pdftex-a` myself, though the backgrounds *are* a bit glitchy (they don't seem to have the proper "depth", so that some of the text hangs off of them at the end of most screens).

Answer (score 23):

I normally don't care much for actual physical references, but [The LaTeX Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201362996) is fantastic; it covers everything in LaTeX, and quite a few of the more popular packages

Answer (score 22):

I have to say I tend to 'texdoc <package>' for most of my requirements. Tikz and beamer feature quite heavily, and as a programmer 'TeX by Topic' is hard to beat.

Comment: Link to *TeX by Topic: A TeXnician's Reference* by Victor Eijkhout: http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html

Comment: Or 'texdoc texbytopic'

Answer (score 21):

Not to forget Tobias Oetikers "[The Not So Short Introduction to Latex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)"
Or via `texdoc lshort`

Answer (score 16):

Although it can struggle with more obscure symbols. I use [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) when I need to look up a symbol name. It is a little applet that does image recognition on hand drawn latex symbols and spits out a few likely candidates and their respective commands.

Answer (score 13):

My book shelf is quite full, but in practice I do not use any of those, except when I occasionally have to do some LaTeX. So:

**TeX**

- *The TeXBook*. Eijkhout's TeX by Topic may be easier to read for general use, but when you need the absolute final answer to a question, nothing beats Knuth's own manual.

**LaTeX**

- *The LaTeX Companion.* As said, I do not use LaTeX a lot, but when I do, I find this the easiest way to look something up.

**ConTeXt**

- The [ConTeXt Wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/)'s search box. There are quite a lot of manuals about ConTeXt, but the wiki is the most valuable resource, for me.

Answer (score 12):

At work I have the beamer and pgf manuals open about 50% of the time.  *The TeXbook* is one of the most thumbed books I own.  But I also would like to recommend *[A Guide to LaTeX](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201398257)* by Kopka and Daly.  A very nice guide that starts from basics and ends with a bit of programming.

Answer (score 10):

Even though that these days few people use AMS-TeX I have to mention beautiful 
Michael Spivak's book [Joy of TeX](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821829971) as well as [the Advanced TeXbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387945563). I am sure many of older package writers have used the second one to learn the tools of the trade.

Answer (score 9):

I don't keep a local copy, but I usually find that [the LaTeX WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) has most of the answers for my everyday questions.

Comment: Do you know if there are .tex files which output this .pdf ?

Comment: Sadly, the advice in the LaTeX WikiBook is not always accurate, or observant of best practices.  My attempts to correct errors were summarily rejected, so I gave up.

Answer (score 8):

I don't really have a shelf, but a folder full of references; one I use quite often is the [The Visual LaTeX FAQ](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/visualFAQ/visualFAQ.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Besides what has already been mentioned, a great reference for low-level TeX stuff is David Bausum's "TeX Reference Manual", of which there is an [online version](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/trm.html) available.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain how useful it is these days, but I feel that I ought to mention Leslie Lamport's original book "A Document Preparation System - LaTeX - User's Guide and Reference Manual" from 1986. I grabbed it from a guy who was retiring at the last place I worked. It's actually still pretty good for beginners.

I have that, Knuth's 'TeXbook' and 'Metafont', and Kopka and Daly's `Guide to LaTeX2e'.

I also use `texdoc` a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I got various TeX-related books, all the companions for example. Nowadays I usually use the 2nd edition companion and `texdoc`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not actually a real documentation but I usually keep it open just next to the pdfs mentioned above. [Qtikz](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language) comes in quite handy for quick testing tikz pictures and command tryouts. It also saved my day a few times.

Comment: Now a new `tikzedt` has come with new features.

Comment: @percusse Bbbbbut that's is cheating. (Seems useful though.)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Why do you think so?

Comment: @percusse Real TikZies just use TeX. (It was a joke:-)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Hahah, sorry. I'm not very smart these days (finalizing the thesis). More tuna fish needed.

Comment: @percusse Good luck with the thesis.

Answer (score 2):

For those who read Czech: [TeXbook naruby](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/olsak/tbn.html) (TeXbook inside out) ([PDF](ftp://math.feld.cvut.cz/pub/olsak/tbn/tbn.pdf)) is an excellent textbook/reference for low-level TeX.

Comment: That is related only by the author, but not by content — what you references describes Olsak's set of macros on top of TeX (LaTeX-like) whereas "TeXbook inside out" is a low-level textbook of TeX internals.

Comment: No problem. Yes, it looks lower-level, I did not look into so much detail before (quite a feat for 1 person to maintain this, btw).

Answer (score 2):

The reference manual for the expl3 programming environment, [Latex3 Interfaces](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I just read the everywhere acclaimed here book: `lshort` i.e. The not so short intro to latex, and i found that LOTs of items are ditto same on both these sources. I don't know which copied from where. And now, since most content is same, so, for several reasons (lack of updates to pdf, lack of proper maintenance, among other things), I will also not recommend wikibook.

**Apend:** Wikibook itself in [this section](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Scientific_Reports&oldid=4056340#Further_reading) itself recommends `lshort` and [dicimaw-latex-thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html)

---

I also find that LaTeX wikibook is an extremely good place for the beginners (which I am) and giving me pointers on where to go next.

And the "next" place is usually the particular package's documentation.

*

Comment: Sadly, the LaTeX Wikibook often does not observe "best practices", and is sometimes just plain wrong.  However, `lshort` is reliable, and therefore recommended for general principles.

Comment: Although one can probably guess the answer anyway to which came first (and therefore which was probably the original of any copy), to put concrete figures on it, `lshort` dates back at least to 1995 (according to its [copyright](https://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf#page=2)), whereas the first commit to the Wikibook was in [2005](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX&oldid=87017).

Comment: wow, that's nice @LSpice

Answer (score 1):

Herbert Voss's `mathmode` document mentioned in the main question is, as its URL http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode suggests, now marked obsolete.  However, user @Su-47 points out in an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428766) to [What happened to mathmode documentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352428/what-happened-to-mathmode-documentation) that there is an updated version, [Typesetting mathematics with LaTeX](https://www.tug.org/%7Ehvoss/PDF/mathmode.pdf), available at [https://www.tug.org/~hvoss](https://www.tug.org/%7Ehvoss).

Answer (score 0):

I basically have the documentation to all packages Stefan Kottwitz posted earlier, with the exception for the

**Bibliography:** [BibLaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) in combination with [BibLaTeX-chem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem) for some styles.

But what I really wanted to add are some very useful tools for typesetting

**Chemistry:** [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for every kind of SI-Unit necessary. [The chemstyle bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemstyle), which is implementing a floating environment for schemes, but the best thing about it is on how to enumerate chemical compound within eps figures. And last, not least the [bpchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bpchem) package for correct enumeration.

Comment: `chemstyle` doesn't do the numbering of compounds but uses either `chemcompounds` (default) or `bpchem` for the task. However, there is the more comprehensive `chemnum` which also allows numbering of compounds within EPS figures. Related: there is also the [tag:chemmacros] bundle consisting of four packages with loads of goodies for chemists.

Answer (score 0):

My first exposure to LaTeX documentation was Lamport's book, cited elsewhere here. But overall, the most useful reference I had while getting "up to speed" have been the various editions of George Grätzer's *Math into LaTeX* The current version in print is:

- George Grätzer, *More Math Into LaTeX*, 5th edition, 2016, Springer.

I still come back to it from time to time, even though I make considerable use of *The LaTeX Companion* (3rd ed.) and, of course, lots of `texdoc` calls.