# Good LaTeX book for Math beginner

Tags: books, learning

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Which manuals are on your “TeX Reference” shelf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66/which-manuals-are-on-your-tex-reference-shelf)
>   [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)

Any suggestion for a good LaTeX book for a math beginner, I have experience programming Perl and shell scripts, but that's about it.  Amazon gives me tons of results, I don't know which one to go with.

Thanks!

Comment: This is rather offtopic here. There is a sister site dedicated to TeX, and google should provide lots of useful (and free!) suggestions...

Comment: @KerxPhilo: This question has been already answered: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex

Comment: @Mariano, thanks for migrating, I wasn't aware there was a TeX/LaTeX site.

Comment: @Gonzalo, I guess this question can be closed.  I didn't know this site existed, so I didn't get a chance to search for it. Thanks!

Comment: Also this question might help you: [Which manuals are on your “TeX Reference” shelf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66/which-manuals-are-on-your-tex-reference-shelf)

Answer (score 4):

Expected this month, March 2011: [LaTeX Beginner's Guide](https://www.packtpub.com/latex-beginners-guide/book).

This book offers a practical introduction to LaTeX with a lot of examples. It deals with LaTeX in general, further of course also with math typesetting.
The book is written for beginners, it also covers installation and usage.

It's also available as ebook or as bundle paperback+ebook.