# Where can I find the standard LaTeX reference manual?

Tags: documentation

Like a semi-detailed user manual for LaTeX commands (`\newtheorem`, etc).

Comment: Have a look at the answers given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/14 . You might find something helpful.

Comment: For crosslinking purpose only. Special case of [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined) I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd start with [The not so short guide to LaTeX](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), and then have a look at

[Which manuals are on your "TeX Reference" shelf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66/which-manuals-are-on-your-tex-reference-shelf)

Answer (score 10):

One document that deserves to be better known is the [LaTeX2e Reference Manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html).

Comment: I just quickly reviewed it and I will add this to my short list of 'best' references for my students.

Comment: It’s BTW part of MiKTeX and TeXLive!

Comment: `texdoc latex2e` at the command prompt will lead directly to the pdf of LaTeX reference manual both in miktex and texlive distro

Answer (score 5):

I have my students use The LateX Wikibook http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX.  It is a required class for freshman math majors.  This is the second year it has been the textbook.

Comment: Are there .tex files for the .pdf in the link. I am looking for them to get the most recent version available