# How do I tell which version of a command to use?

Tags: best-practices

So LaTeX has a lot of commands that do very similar things. Often this is a result of some of these being old.

For example: `$x^2$` vs `\(^2\)`; As I understand it, the second example is the more modern version and should be used when possible.

Other examples: [`\it` vs the more modern `\itshape` and the one I'm actually supposed to use `\textit{}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)

I've heard enough mention of these that I think I know which one I'm supposed to use; however, there are also things like [`\begin{center}` vs `\centering`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/7880) where it is contextual (Due to vertical spacing)

These are examples I picked off the top of my head; `$$...$$` vs `\[...\]` vs `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` is another one that someone mentioned below.

Is there an easy way to tell which command I'm supposed to use when? For stuff from packages, it is usually easy to look at the manuals and see which is more up to date, but what about core LaTeX stuff? Is there a list of when to use various versions of commands? Or better yet, a general rule of thumb so I can tell if I should be learning a new way to do things?

Comment: `nag` package seems useful to address some concerns

Comment: Browse {[tag:best-practices]}? `;)`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Techniques and packages to keep up with good practices](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19264/15717) and [Best practices references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577/15717)

Comment: I am not sure this is a duplicate. The OP is not asking which practice is best, but how we decide that it is. I would tend to agree with @David – you don't, because it depends on what you want to achieve. When some "old" commands have inner workings that work better for your purposes, why not use them?

Comment: Also [texdef script to track out definition of (LA)TEX commands](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/support/texdef/texdef.pdf) and latex command reference [texdoc latex2e](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48006/15717) with [fixltx2e](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fixltx2e.pdf)

Comment: All of those have questions on them already; I was hoping for a more general method (All switch type commands have been replaced by macro type, for example)

Comment: @texenthusiast Those both seems more general; I'm looking at commands I'd likely see in old documents (like \bf) that I shouldn't copy to a modern document, and if there is a general table of old vs new versions or such.

Comment: @doncherry I actually subscribed to {best-practices} for a long time, but most of the stuff was either over my head or esoteric.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. `$...$` is mentioned in the LaTeX manual as a ‘shorthand’ for `\(...\)`. We know that it's not really so, but the manual doesn't go into the details of TeX programming, so this is a good approximation to the truth, for the purposes of the manual, which recommends `$...$` for *very short* formulas, recommending `\(...\)` for longer ones.
2. Commands such as `\it` and `\bf` have been formally declared obsolete. So they shouldn't be used. End of the story.
3. `$$...$$` is not mentioned in the manual and we know it's wrong to use it in LaTeX for various good reasons.
4. Several commands have a ‘double’ form, but this is not really true. There is a noticeable difference between

   ```
   Your {\itshape hovercraft} is full of eels
   ```

   and

   ```
   Your \textit{hovercraft} is full of eels
   ```

   but this doesn't mean `\itshape` shouldn't be used. Its better place is in definition of environments, say

   ```
   \newenvironment{iquote}{\begin{quote}\itshape}{\end{quote}}
   ```

   that defines the `iquote` environment which typeset a quote in italics. Using `\textit` would be wrong here.
5. There are some pairs: `\raggedright` and `flushleft`, `\raggedleft` and `flushright`, `\centering` and `center`. This is similar to the distinction between font switch and font command discussed above. The ‘switch’ form, say `\centering`, is better used for defining environments, since `center` also leaves some space above and below the centered text; the same for `flushleft` and `flushright`. Note that all switches here need an explicit paragraph termination at the end, be it given by `\par` or by an `\end{...}` command that provides it, for instance `\end{quote}`. So, if you need ragged right quotes, you can define

   ```
   \newenvironment{rquote}{\begin{quote}\raggedright}{\end{quote}}
   ```
6. `\[...\]` is equivalent to `\begin{displaymath}...\end{displaymath}` but *very* different from `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, because the latter also adds a number to the equation. There's a reason why `amsmath` defines the `equation*` environment: it's easier to change an equation from `equation` to `equation*` (or conversely) than from `equation` to `displaymath`.
7. Some constructions that one finds in LaTeX documents are actually foreign. Examples are `\centerline`, `\llap`, `\hbox`. A savvy (or macho) LaTeX programmer can profit from them, but it's better to stick with LaTeX's corresponding commands

   ```
   \makebox[\columnwidth]{...}
   \makebox[0pt][r]{...}
   \mbox{...}
   ```

   in a LaTeX document, reserving the lower level commands for packages and using them when one ***knows*** what they do, which is not intuitive.

An example. Just a few hours ago I answered a question originating from a strange behavior of a macro a user found on the net. The proposed code used mysterious parameters such as `\hoffset`; the code I suggested uses normal LaTeX commands, with the exception of `\bgroup`, `\egroup` and `\dimexpr` (these are always in the toolbox of a LaTeX programmer). The difference is between non working and working code. `;-)`.

Comment: Wait, hbox is a weird one? I see that used all the time...

Comment: So how do to tell which are lower level commands and which I should be using?

Comment: @Canageek Refer to “official” documentation: the manual and the package documentations.

Answer (score 13):

The  answer is "you don't" but unfortunately the site won't allow short and to the point answers, so a more discursive one...

> For example: `$x^2$` vs `\(^2\)`; As I understand it, the second example 
>   is the more modern version and should be used when possible.

Well not really more modern; `\(` has been in LaTeX from the start, although `$` is a TeX primitive so in a sense is older. `\(` is intended to give better error diagnostics as the system can tell that `\(zzz\(` doesn't match up whereas if you miss out a `$` things just go out of parity with intended math start becoming math close, and you get weird errors. Unfortunately the standard definition of `\(` is fragile whereas `$` is robust so if you use it in say `\caption` you get *very* weird errors. So it's an example of an error detecting mechanism that has generated more errors than it detected. The `fixltx2e` package makes `\(` robust, but if people know enough to use that package they don't make so many simple math mode delimiter errors anyway...

> Other examples: `\it` vs the more modern `\itshape` and the one I'm
>   actually supposed to use `\textit{}`

There you don't necessarily have a choice, `\it` is simply not defined in the LaTeX2e format. `article` and some other classes define

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
```

so you can pretend it's the 1980's again

> I've heard enough mention of these that I think I know which one I'm
>   supposed to use; however, there are also things like `\begin{center}` vs
>   `\centering`

These do different things: `\begin{center}` uses `\centering` internally to do the centering, but it is also a latex display environment (a list) so sets the content off with vertical space. So it depends if you just want to centre something or if you want to make a centred display.

Comment: So I'm hearing there is no rule of thumb to tell if I should be looking on TeX.SX to see if there is a newer version of that command?

Comment: @Canageek There's always a newer version, it doesn't definitely mean it's better or that you you use it. Tikz is newer than pstricks which is newer than the picture environment in latex, but the last of those still have advantages in terms of portability and speed (if not raw power:-)  similarly xcolor and enumitem are newer than color and enumerate, but I know the older ones better.

Answer (score 5):

In short:

> For example: $x^2$ vs (^2); As I understand it, the second example
>   is the more modern version and should be used when possible.

Rather not. The first is safer. But in the case of `\[ \]` and `$$ $$` the first is preferrred.

> Other examples: \it vs the more modern \itshape and the one I'm
>   actually supposed to use \textit{}

`\textit` also makes proper italic correction.

> I've heard enough mention of these that I think I know which one I'm
>   supposed to use; however, there are also things like \begin{center} vs
>   \centering

`\begin{center}` adds additional vertical spacing, `\centering` - not.

Comment: So I'm hearing there is no rule of thumb to tell if I should be looking on TeX.SX to see if there is a newer version of that command?

Comment: @Canageek If you want information about new version, than rather in documentation of new distributions or on CTAN. But if you want to show your experiments here, near surely you may expect constructive comments.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of questions, you can refer to the "*[An essential guide to LATEX2ε usage](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf)*" which discusses obsolete commands and packages. Versions of other languages can also be found on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu).