# How to write an equation in LaTeX?

Tags: equations

How do I write this equation in LaTeX?

Vo = ( R1/( R1+R4)-R2/(R2+R3)  ) x Vs

Comment: Negative points seem unfair.  We'd like to encourage people to use LaTeX and not run off people just because they don't know how to get started. The op doesn't know what to do.  Minimally you could say something helpful.

Comment: It might be good for you to check out some of the suggestions at [Where can I find the standard LaTeX reference manual?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47958/22413)

Comment: This is usually where people ask questions when they are stuck, particularly *after* searching for answers on this site and elsewhere. In addition to @A.Ellett's suggestion, the [Mathematics section of the LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) should be straightforward and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A quickly coded option.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
 \[V_o = \left(\frac{ R_1}{( R_1+R_4)}-\frac{R_2}{(R_2+R_3)} \right)V\]
\end{document}
```

Now I strongly recommend you go online and begin to read any one of the many fine introductions to LaTeX e.g. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

Or read this for more good choices of introductions to LaTeX [How to write an equation in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237642/how-to-write-an-equation-in-a-report)

Answer (score 0):

There a a number of online equation editors that can be useful to familiarise yourself with the mathematical syntax of LaTeX.

Here are two such editors that provide live updates:

http://www.hostmath.com/

http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php