# Where are the reference docs?

Tags: documentation

I'm just getting started with LaTeX, so likely missing something simple. I'm just looking for docs: how to get started, what commands do what, etc.

I found [the documentation page](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/), but all it seems to provide is a link to a document describing differences between LaTeX 2 and 2e, neither of which I have any familiarity with.

Is there a good, online resource that acts as a kind of reference documentation for LaTeX?

Comment: source2e.pdf is available in every LaTeX distribution, but this is probably not for getting started.

Comment: the official documentation are books (the latex book and the latex companion from Addison-Wesley but ther are plenty of good free tutorials (the not so short introduction to latex being a good start)

Comment: OK, I just found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47958/where-can-i-find-the-standard-latex-reference-manual). It's a bit strange to me that there are no official docs, but OK let me dig further.

Comment: @me-- As noted, there is an official reference: _LaTeX: A Document Preparation System_, Leslie Lamport, Addison-Wesley, 1994, ISBN 0201529831.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by no official documentation, the official documentation is a published book.

Comment: may i recommend "latex for complete novices", by nicola talbot: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/  not "official" but very good indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal or a command window and run

```
 texdoc latex
```