# How does quotchap package deal with chapters read from external files?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, quotchap

If I use the `quotchap` package, with the following sample code,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[grey]{quotchap}
\begin{document}
\input{ch1}
\chapter{Chapter 2 Heading}
\end{document}
```

it recognizes chapter 2 as chapter 1, and does not assign a number to the first chapter which is read from the following file:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\begin{quote}
A quote.
\end{quote}
```

Any hint for this problem?

Comment: That because you used `\chapter*` in the file. The starred variant produces an unnumbered chapter heading (which also doesn't step the chapter counter).

Comment: the chapter definition in your file specifically says not to number that chapter, this is what the `*` in `\chapter*{}` mean.

Comment: Thanks. That indeed was the reason.  If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Tarek this is somewhat basic knowledge. Have you read an introductory to LaTeX already? (See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384/latex-introductions-in-languages-other-than-english, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66/which-manuals-are-on-your-tex-reference-shelf).

Comment: @cgnieder Not sure what the problem is with basic knowledge. Is this website now only for experts? Let's be a bit more understanding with those getting started with LaTeX. Saying things like "this is basic knowledge" "go read an introductory LaTeX book" are not helpful and is in my opinion mean. The links are useful, though.

Comment: @Vivi There's no problem at all! I didn't want to sound rude (English is not my native language so I can't be sure, though, that I haven't). Since the starred versions of the sectioning commands are mentioned in _every_ basic introductory I know it appeared natural that the OP hasn't read any, yet...

Comment: @cgnieder I don't think English was the issue. My problem is that your comment implies that his question is too obvious (he is stupid? the website only takes expert questions?) and that he didn't do his homework. How do we know he didn't read an introductory book? Learning LaTeX can be daunting, and we don't remember everything we read. He thought the problem was with the quotchap package; he didn't even know it was with the use of \chapter.

Comment: @cgnieder Anyway, as it was correctly pointed out to me, I was the rude one in the end. My problem is not with you, but with what I think is a growing tendency of the website to be elitist. I also think that it would have been helpful to write an explicit comment saying that you are voting to close the question and why ("I am voting to close this question because... This is just to keep the place tidy but we encourage you to ask questions blah blah). I don't think it would be good to discourage newbies to be asking questions.

Comment: @Vivi Why would not knowing basic knowledge mean someone's stupid? Not knowing something has nothing to do with intelligence! You're right I can't know Tarek didn't read an introduction. But does that mean I mustn't suggest to read one? And Tarek's question got answered (_before_ the question got closed and I made my suggestion), didn't it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6728/discussion-between-cgnieder-and-vivi)

Comment: @Tarek I hope you didn't get the wrong impression and are still going to ask any question that might arise! Also: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks Vivi and cgnieder for the keen desire to help me without hurting my feelings, I really appreciate it.  As a matter of fact, I have been using latex for a few years, but this is the first time I use the book class and numbered chapters. When I was trying to solve this problem myself, I fiddled with the ' * ', but probably that was in combination with some other mistake which I did. Thanks again.