# How to write ':' and '_' in equation?

Tags: equations, text-manipulation

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:policy}
\(\text{[DIP:10.1.0.17] $\rightarrow$ F $\rightarrow$ L}\)
\end{equation}
```

Gives me many errors like `! Missing $ inserted` and `Bad math environment delimiter`. How do I remove these errors?

Comment: Remove the `\(` and `\)` from `equation` environment -- it's already math-mode.  If it were me, though, I would go through and see what actually *needs* to be in math-mode - the code is a bit wonky as it stands.

Comment: It seems like you're lacking some basic fundamentals of math mode in LaTeX. Perhaps consider reading the [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english). Also, you might consider it useful to view [Which manuals are on your “TeX Reference” shelf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got your math-modes mixed up.

Consider:

```
\begin{equation}
                                 % In math mode now!
  \(                             % in math mode... again?
    \text{                       % text exits math mode temporarily
      [DIP:10.1.0.17]
      $                          % wait, back in math mode?
      \rightarrow$               % and out again
      F
      $                          % back in math mode
      \rightarrow$               % and out again
      L}                         % back in (out of \text)
  \)                             % and out
\end{equation}                   % and out again??
```

(Spaces added for clarity.)

You main problem was math-mode-inception.  You can't enter math mode twice (nor exit it twice).

Consider using the following instead:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:policy}
  \text{[DIP:10.1.0.17]} \rightarrow \text{F} \rightarrow \text{L}
\end{equation}
```

[image: output]

To add an underscore, use it as a control sequence:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:policy}
  \text{[DIP:10.1.0.17]} \rightarrow \text{F} \rightarrow \text{L\_}
\end{equation}
```

[image: underscore]

(By the way, this control-sequence technique is used for most special characters (`$%#_{}&`) - see [Escape character in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex).  If you have experience in programming C-like languages, think of it as an 'escape'.)

Comment: You can borrow my output image from my answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

### Version 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\(\text{[DIP:10.1.0.17] $\rightarrow$ F $\rightarrow$ L\_}\)

\end{document}
```

### Version 2:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\text{[DIP:10.1.0.17] $\rightarrow$ F $\rightarrow$ L\_}
\label{eq:something}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to change the document class to meet  your requirement.

Comment: Good answer, but this doesn't really explain what went wrong -- it would be helpful for learning's sake, at least.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:policy}
\text{[DIP:10.1.0.17] $\rightarrow$ F $\rightarrow$ L}
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
\text{[DIP:10.1.0.17]} \rightarrow F \rightarrow L
\end{equation}
```

Your main error was that you tried to enter math mode inside of an `equation` environment, where you were already in math mode.  For the first display above I just removed your `\(` and `\)`; for the second one, I also made the `\text` apply to only the business in between the square brackets.  That way, the F and the L appear as math symbols.