# What happened to mathmode documentation?

Tags: math-mode, documentation, texdoc

There used to be a document distributed with TeXLive that contained a very nice description of the many different math modes, when they should be used, with examples of how to do it. I could easily open that document by issuing the command `texdoc mathmode`. Now that doesn't work.

I've searched online and can't find the document. Does it still exist, and if so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The document still exists as [`mathmode`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode?lang=en) but it is considered *obsolete* with this "disclaimer":

> The au­thor con­sid­ers this pack­age now as be­ing too old and af­flicted with too many ty­po­graph­i­cal bugs. That’s why it has been clas­si­fied as "ob­so­lete", at least for the time be­ing.

Answer (score 5):

Because of the reasons Werner named, Herbert Voß, the author of `mathmode` wrote a [replacement](https://www.tug.org/%7Ehvoss) for the `mathmode`. He called it Typesetting mathematics with LaTeX (version 0.34, from 2023/2/10, checked on 2024/1/30).

Thank @gusbrs for the hints!

Comment: I got here from review as well. Even though the points raised before are usually sound, the question here is where to find the document in question. So, the link is the answer, and contain its "essential parts". But otherwise, I do agree that some more context on the link provided would be welcome.

Comment: Hello @Teepeemm! Thank you for your comment. I disagree with you. If someone ask, where this person can find a document, why is it wrong, just to say, where this person can find the searched document? Other question: Should I better edit the answer of Werner? Or is it better to copy-paste the information, which provided the author of `mathmode` behind the link, I posted? On the other side I agree the rules of TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange and I'm ready to edit my answer, so please say me, what I have to change and I will see, what I can do.

Comment: @Su-47, as you asked, I think some more information in your answer would be welcome, as I mentioned. For example, it is nice to know that this is by the same author as the previous document, and that it is different from the old one etc. Some more context. But that's just my opinion. I believe your answer is useful already, just could be a little more. ;)

Comment: Hello, I don't find a document or link called "Typesetting mathematics with LaTeX" in https://www.tug.org/~hvoss or by google. Where can I find it?

Comment: @ahe_borriglione, its true, the file is gone. I don't know the reason. I find it [here](http://www.gang.umass.edu/~franz/latexmanual.pdf).

Comment: @Su-47 In the beginning of the document, it says at the bottom of the page before the content `Only for private use! It is not allowed to save this document on a server!` It's unclear what the reaons are, but with the exclamation marks, it seems Mr. Voss felt very strongly about this (at least at one point in time).

Comment: The document is (back?) up, and with updates as recently as 2023 January 9 (according to https://tug.org/~hvoss) or 2023 February 10 (according to https://tug.org/~hvoss/PDF/mathmode.pdf). Thanks for the pointer to this very useful document!  I have also shared the link as an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708175) to [Which manuals are on your "TeX Reference" shelf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66/which-manuals-are-on-your-tex-reference-shelf).