# Preface vs. Chapter 1

Tags: numbering, chapters

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{Preface}

\chapter{Some set theory}
\end{document}
```

But **now** I'm getting *Preface* numbered as a chapter 1. How can I avoid this ?

To make things faster I have 2 not completely related questions :
How can I insert a TeX source A.tex without `\begin{document}` to a master file and how can I number
equations generally and consistently for all such inserted documents ?
I.e. if the Chapter number is 2, then the equation in it should be

`2.3.1

2.3.2`
etc.

Comment: There are two ways to avoid numbering the preface.  (1) After `\begin{document}` insert `\frontmatter`, and just before the first `\chapter`, insert `\mainmatter`.  (2) Enter the preface as `\chapter*`.  Off topic: you have loaded `amsmath` twice; it''s a good thing the option `fleqn` was entered with the first load, otherwise it would be ignored.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Please how do I achieve a consistent numbering across pages. I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x59u0.jpg) but I need something like `1.1. ZF` `1.2 ZF`....`1.3 for some finitely many elements` `1.4.for all other i`. So I need that every equation in a chapter 1 is preceeded by `1 .` and that a second coordinate is **always** increased by 1 in that chapter 1.

Comment: Please don't ask several unrelated questions in the same "question".

Comment: If a subsidiary file begins with `\chapter`, you can incorporate it with `\include{A}`.  If the file begins with something else, use `\input{A}`.  To number equations withing sections, specify `\counterwithin{equation}{section}`.  You should really look at a reference manual.  There are some good xuggestions here: [Which manuals are on your "TeX Reference" shelf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry my English is poor to read a manual. **Where** should I put/specify this command  `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` it doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Note that I need to number `enumerate` not `eqyation`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have put it at both places, at the top of `include{A}` and under and above the chapter. Nothing works.

Comment: Numbering `enumerate` can't be done with `counterwithin`.  Please ask a new question about that.